# iphone add effects to images

Tags: iphone, image, effects

Please tel me if there are apple libraries or 3party libraries available for adding effects such sepia greyscale glow comic book color pencil etc to images.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this could help you :

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/photoshopframew/

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

Answer (score 0):

Apple (as far as I know) does not have any image processing/manipulation libraries for the iOS released at the moment ... however this may change when SDK 5.0 is released.

As far as 3rd party image effect libraries the only one I have been able to locate is:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

which is a good but rather basic library with simple effects like edge detection, blur, and black and white.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had seen it earlier. Is there any way we can get code for the above? There are many applications which have implemented them

Comment: @droidme Sorry for the late reply. You can checkout a read-only copy of the source code.     "svn checkout http://simple-iphone-image-processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ simple-iphone-image-processing-read-only"     Just type or copy that into terminal and copy the files/folder into your project.

Comment: thanks for the link. Can you please tell me which are the effects the above code is meant for.

Comment: @droidme The code is good for simple image processing including: Canny Edge Detection, Histogram Equalisation, Skeletonisation, Thresholding, Gaussian Blur, Brightness Normalisation, Region Extraction, Resizing. This is taken right from its website, you can read all about the codes functionality at http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this one: [Filtrr for iOS](https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr)

Answer (score 0):

More than 50 filters are available in the following github source code....just follow the instructions to integrate in your project.github link is [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) .